# AS3 AutoSize Textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

in AS3, I'm making this dynamic textfield that is populated from an XML file based on where the user clicks.

The dynamic textfield has a custom scrollbar to it. My problem is that if the text inserted into the textfield is less than the previously displayed text, you can still scroll the dynamic textfield as far as the previous one.

Is there a way to reset the textfield autoSize?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000885.html) will tell you exactly what to do.

<s>Are you using any of the standard flex controls? Or, is this flash?</s>

You can set the width of the field to the string length + some space (by binding the width to the string's length/event handling etc). [This](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Text_08.html) may be of interest. Of course,

Comment: arrrg.. code does not display correctly. Anyway, is Flash, and see... the textfield never disappear the stage it just updates the text. Does it help?

Comment: Then it is not a `dynamic textfield`. Only, the text is. I'll update my answer with a link.

Comment: there are 2 links (1st and last line respectively). Check the one on the first line.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Flash ( I have very little experience in Flex ) then the  [textField.autosize](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary729.html) property would probably get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, wrap the xml elements text in

```
<text><![CDATA[<span class="someClass">Some Text Here</span>]]></text>
```

If the prior wasn't wrapped in `CDATA`, flash would have taken the `<span class="someClass">` and attempted to drop it down a line and indent it as you would with XML hierarchy; `CDATA` tells flash to ignore those characters and literally treat them as a string.  The result of not using this process is that there are many odd spacings in your textfield.

Also be sure that your `TextField` is set to Multiline and wordwrap, as well as `autoSize` such as `TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT`;